# TextView and Button get stuck in the top-left corner of the blueprint in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

When I add a TextView and Button to a Blueprint in Android Studio then it gets stuck in the top-left corner of the Blueprint.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue. Click on the "Auto connection to Parent " button(Icon looks like letter "U" (magnet symbol). It is on the Left Top of the Design view

Comment: Solved my problem perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little late, but you need to add the following to styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Note `Base.` pre-pended to the parent theme.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ConstraintLayout then you need to give proper constraints. Otherwise use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

Comment: I changed layout to relative, but still when I drag the button, textview or whatever all just run to the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Use the designer in Android Studio to set upper, left and right constraints and then test again.

Or just edit your XML file like this
example:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="test"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FFCD00"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Please post your XML layout file, for more help.

Comment: I copied and paste it in my XML textview, but still the textview is at the top left corner. I can not move it by more. it literally is immobile. If you look at the picture I uploaded, there is a little small white dot.

Answer (score -1):

Any build problems and errors?
I don't see anything in you picture you uploaded, so I guess that some problems in your project. Please check gradle output and system output to find it out.

Comment: I just do not want to make use of the constraint layout. Yeah I have 2 problems. Rendering problem and Failed to initiate one or two classes. How can I get rid of these?