# Buttons getting stuck in top left corner of Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, constraints, android-button

I've seen quite a few solutions to this problem but non which I seem to be able to implement. I'm really new to Android Studio, but Fragments seems so straight forward and "simple". However before I could even get going with coding functionality all the buttons I added to my mainFragment got stuck in the upper left corner. [image]

Further, I cannot seem to add a constraint the way I usually do it in my xml-code, when I write "app:cons" nothing comes up.

I've heard about a "Auto connection to Parent" button but I cannot for the life of me seem to find it. Read about it here [TextView and Button get stuck in the top-left corner of the blueprint in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056109/textview-and-button-get-stuck-in-the-top-left-corner-of-the-blueprint-in-android)

I tried looking for a "Auto connection  to Parent" button.
I tried recreating the fragment.
I tried to restart to program.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your parent layout **FrameLayout** to **androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout** or **RelativeLayout**

Comment: Thank you! That helped, so irritating when the solution is so simple. I've spent 2 hours on this conundrum. This solved the issue!